# Почему "гром и молния", а не наоборот?

Tags: фразеология

Сначала мы видим молнию, а потом слышим гром. Почему принято говорить "гром и молния", а не "молния и гром" ?

Такой порядок не только в русском, но и в нескольких других языках. Подробнее: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/273976/123571

Comment: Похоже, простое удобство произношения.

Comment: Пока гром не грянет, мужик не перекрестится!

Answer (score 2):

Ну по большому счету ничего удивительного тут нет. 
Известно, что фразеологизм идет из древней Греции, где Зевс метал громы и молнии (хотя назван был Громовержцем), а Гефест его молниями этим снабжал. Гром был наиболее существенной частью этого образа, люди боялись именно грома, молния воспринималась в лучшем случае как предвестник грома (хотя реально - наоборот, но такова уж природа человеческих чувств), или вообще одно с другим (конкретная молния с порождаемым ей громом) не сопоставлялось.  Сравните с современным "громоотвод", который "отводит" как раз молнии.

Все остальные из ценного - перепевы и уточнения этой версии.
Кое что вот есть тут.
http://speakrus.ru/31/f3192.htm
(там надо покопаться, обсуждение разбросано по нескольким страницам)

Comment: Известно, что фразеолгизм идет из Древней Греции - кому это известно? Подтверждение есть?

Comment: Чего подтверждение? Что известно? Кому? - Ну, видимо, не вам.

Comment: Приведите хоть доказательство, что это выражение именно в таком виде существовало в древнегреческом. Цитату, например. Иначе утверждение голословное и выглядит довольно-таки сомнительно.

Comment: Поищите хоть одну серьезную версию, отличную от Зевса. https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%B8+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Вы мне даете ссылки на мнения, а я хочу ссылку на факт. То, что множество людей верит именно в эту версию, не делает её верной. Точно так же множество людей верило, что гром — это грохот колёс от колесницы Зевса, а молнии — его копья, но к реальности это не имело отношения.

Comment: есть ли доказательства того, что 1) фразеологизм именно в таком виде существовал в древнегреческом и 2) из древнегреческого он попал в русский каким-то путём?

Comment: Я не Вам даю. Я даю тем, кому это интересен ответ на ваш вопрос. Вы, видимо, к ним не относитесь. Всё. Все - в чат.

Answer (score 1):

Гром мы услышим в любом случае: находясь в доме с закрытыми окнами или находясь с закрытыми глазами. Наверное поэтому он первичен.

Comment: ИМХО Фонетика и фразеология. Фразеологизм должен удобно произноситься, а обратный порядок для этой фонетической фразы нехорош, да и графика тоже (...ИИИ подряд)) Все остальные доводы объяснительного характера, отсюда и разные мнения.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя бы потому, что если не смотреть постоянно на небо, то сперва слышишь гром, а лишь потом обращаешь внимание на молнию. Учитывая же, что молнии воспринимались как кара господня и внушала суеверный ужас (природу грозы установили лишь в XIX веке), для наблюдения за небом под ливневым дождём с грозою нужна была недюжинная смелость.

Comment: Разве? Я всегда сначала вижу молнию, а потом слышу гром.

Comment: @NickVolynkin В городе, из окна, чувствуя себя в безопасности? Раньше у людей не было подобной роскоши.

Comment: Молния может быть спрятана в плотных тучах, так что только гром будет слышен...

Comment: @VictorBazarov тогда и был бы просто гром, без молнии.

Comment: Гром кажется "страшнее" молнии, вот он и на первом месте. Как тарарахнет, душа в пятки стремится) Даже железяку на крыше назвали громоотводом,  хотя против грома он и бессилен.

Comment: Марк Из, у Арнольда (если знаете) на спикрус есть объяснение в вашем духе). Когда идет издалека гроза гром воспринимается как нечто близкое, а молния - далекое, сначала даже невидимое. И только в центе грозы молнии начинают казаться чем-то опасным. Ссылка - в моем ответе. Но это опять-таки не обоснование, а лишь некоторое лыко в строку. Кореи надо смотреть в первобытных и языческих верованиях. А непосредственный источник - у греков.

Comment: @behemothus не уверен, что тут есть заимствование, так как конструкция скорее типична для разных народов и верований. Боги грома (именно грома) есть и в мифологиях не связанных с греками. Если к скандинавскому Тору и кельтскому Таранису еще как-то можно приписать их влияние, то к китайскому Лэйгуну, а уж тем более к ацтекскому Тлалоку и майаскому Чаку уже никак. Гром был более важным атрибутом, чем молния, поэтому и назывался первым. Скорее тут можно рассуждать об архитипичности восприятия грозы, чем о заимствованиях.

Comment: Марк Из, а я хоть где написал "заимствование"? Понимаете, тут уже два, если не три, разных вопроса пошло. Почему в таком порядке - объяснимо вне всяких заимствований, согласен.

Comment: А вот популярность самого выражения безусловно так или иначе связана с эллинами. Вообще с ними и с римлянами, как с прародителями всех современных европейских цивилизаций можно смело связывать все, или почти всё, что однозначно не относится только к туркам, финно-угорцам или, там, германцам. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Есть гипотеза, что данное выражение проникло в различные языки из Ветхого Завета (Торы). Цитирую Исход, 19:16:

> На третий день, при наступлении утра, *были громы, и молнии*, и густое облако над горою...

То же на латыни (по ссылкам перевод):

> iam advenerat tertius dies et mane inclaruerat et ecce coeperunt
>   *[audiri](http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/show.php?n=4899) [tonitrua](http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/show.php?n=46113) ac [micare](http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/show.php?n=27916) [fulgura](http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/show.php?n=19150)* et nubes densissima operire montem
>   clangorque bucinae vehementius perstrepebat timuit populus qui erat in
>   castris.

В оригинальной версии на иврите также были "громы и молнии". См.

> [Исход, перевод с иврита на английский](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0219.htm#16). "kolot u'vrakim". "Kolot" — гром (ж.р., мн.ч.), "vrakim" — молния (м.р., мн.ч.).

Сравните:

- английский: "thunder and lightning",
- французский: "tonnerre et la foudre",
- итальянский: "tuoni e fulmini",
- испанский: "truenos y relámpagos".

Comment: Если есть гипотеза, давайте обоснование. Голословно (С).